# RegEx match special character in Dialogflow

Tags: regex, dialogflow-es

I have problem matching with an intent this kind of words "¿Cómo", "¿Que" etc.

I tried creating an entity with the following regex: `¿\w+`. but it doesn't work. Any idea?
Here are some prints of the Intent, Entity and Validation warnings:

Intent detail:
[image: Intent detail]
Entity detail:
[image: Entity detail]
Validation warnings:
[image: Validation Warnings]

Comment: If you use the `\xNN` notation, it seems the warning is no longer shown, `\xBF\w+`

Comment: Thanks, that works! but in lowercase: `\xbf\w+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `\x` notation instead of a literal Unicode char:

```
\xbf\w+
```

where `\xbf` stands for the `¿` char.